# Using cell value as filename for workbook when saving

Tags: vba, excel, save, excel-2010

I have a macro and would like to save the workbook using the value in a cell as the name of the file:  Here is what I have so far.

```
Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String

Sheets("As Adjusted").Select
FPath = "N:\PricingAudit\FY15 Price Increase\ Phase 1 Built Tools"
FName = Sheets("As Adjusted").Range("C4").Text
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName
```

I get a Save as method failed when run.  Any advice would be great.  The only thing I can think of would be that Column C is hidden.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: tell please what value in your `C4` cell? and waht error have you got?

Comment: Try with short path names, and without spaces. Does the path exist? Or is there an accidental space on front of `/ Phase 1 Built Tools`

Comment: Probably doesn't have an extension for the value stored in `C4`.

Comment: It was the space in front of Phase- thanks for the help.

Comment: @SASUSMC - the correct way to say that the problem is solved is to mark the answer that helped you as "accepted" (the little check mark).

Comment: There is no way to mark a comment as the solution.  It was not an answer so I could not mark it.  But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is invalid. There is an extra space in front of `\ Phase 1 Built Tools`.